# df.at got error ValueError: Invalid call for scalar access (getting)

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[1,3,5]})
   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  3
2  3  5
```

when I use `df.at[df['a']==1]` it report error `ValueError: Invalid call for scalar access (getting)!`

but when I use `df.at[df['a']==1,'b'] = 0` it works

```
   a  b
0  1  0
1  2  3
2  3  5
```

Comment: `df['a']==1` is a boolean array and `at` is accessing a single value using an `index`/`col` pair. These are incompatible.

Comment: but why it works in a assignment statement?

Comment: The answer is that you are `getting` in the error condition and `setting` when it works. These work in fundamentally different ways. Under the hood `df.at[df["a"]==1, "b"] = 0` is resolved to `df.loc[df['a']==1, "b"] = 0`

Answer (score 2):

When you call the Boolean just do simple slice will work.

```
df[df['a']==1]
   a  b
0  1  1
```

For your error `.at` only accept the pair index and col combination, notice the index and col should be int or array only contain one `True` value

The reason why you `df.at[df['a']==1,'b'] = 0` work, since df['a']==1 return an array with only one `True`, which just same as input one index number.

If you change `df.at[df['a'].isnull(),'b'] = 0` this will fail.

Comment: first, if I use `df.at[(df['a']==1) | (df['a']==2), 'b'] = 0` it return an array with two `True` and it still works. Second, `df.at[df['a'].isnull(),'b'] = 0` also works, which means it doesn't report error but nothing change.

Comment: @xxyao that is wired behavior, since the official document https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html, mentioned single value assign ~

Comment: It confuses me a lot!